# how deliver multi sms in android?

Tags: android, sms

I wrote a program for sending SMS. My problem is that when I want to send for example five message for my friend and his phone is turned off, after that when he turns on his phone, the delivery just receive for the last SMS. 
My code is shown below:

```
Intent newIntent_sent = new Intent(AppStatics.INTENT_SENT_SMS+this_messageUri);
        Log.d("uri   sending setting", this_messageUri.getPath());

        newIntent_sent.putExtra(AppStatics.INTENT_SENT_ID,this_messageUri.getPath());

        PendingIntent newsentPI  = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0,newIntent_sent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        registerReceiver (new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String uri =  arg1.getExtras().getString(AppStatics.INTENT_SENT_ID);

                Log.d("Uri Sending", uri);

                Send_Result sr = new Send_Result(Uri.parse(uri), getResultCode() );

                Thread tr = new Thread(sr);
                tr.start();

                SendMessegeService.this.unregisterReceiver(this); 
            }

        }, new IntentFilter(AppStatics.INTENT_SENT_SMS+this_messageUri));

        sentPIs.add(newsentPI);


Intent newIntent_deliver = new Intent(AppStatics.INTENT_DELIVERED_SMS+this_messageUri);

        Log.d("Uri deliver Setting", this_messageUri.getPath());

        newIntent_deliver.putExtra(AppStatics.INTENT_DELIVERE_ID,this_messageUri.getPath());

        PendingIntent deliverPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getBaseContext(), 0, newIntent_deliver,0);

        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String uri =  arg1.getExtras().getString(AppStatics.INTENT_DELIVERE_ID);
                Delivery_Result dr = new Delivery_Result(Uri.parse(uri), getResultCode());


                Log.d("Uri deliver", uri);

                Thread tr = new Thread(dr);
                tr.start();
            }
        },new IntentFilter(AppStatics.INTENT_DELIVERED_SMS+this_messageUri));

        deliverPIs.add(deliverPI);
```

and this is my thread class::

```
public class Send_Result implements Runnable
{
    Uri messageUri =null;

    int resultCode ;

    String toastMessage ="";


    public Send_Result(Uri MessageUri,int resultCode)
    {
        this.messageUri = MessageUri;
        this.resultCode=resultCode;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        switch (resultCode) 
        {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                values.put(DataBaseStatics.STATUS,
                        DataBaseStatics.STATUS_PENDING);

                toastMessage = getBaseContext().getResources().getString(R.string.MessageIsSending_Title);

                break;

            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                values.put(DataBaseStatics.STATUS,
                        DataBaseStatics.STATUS_FAILED);
                toastMessage = getBaseContext().getResources().getString(R.string.MessageSendingFailed_Title);
                break;

            default:
                values.put(DataBaseStatics.STATUS,
                        DataBaseStatics.STATUS_FAILED);
                toastMessage = getBaseContext().getResources().getString(R.string.MessageSendingFailed_Title);
                break;

        }
        getBaseContext().getContentResolver().update(
                this_messageUri, values, null, null);

    }

}

public class Delivery_Result implements Runnable
{
    Uri messageUri =null;

    int resultCode ;

    String toastMessage;

    public Delivery_Result(Uri MessageUri,int resultCode)
    {
        this.messageUri = MessageUri;
        this.resultCode=resultCode;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        switch (resultCode) 
        {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK :
                values.put(DataBaseStatics.STATUS, DataBaseStatics.STATUS_COMPLETE);

                toastMessage=getBaseContext().getResources().getString(R.string.MessageDeliverd_Title);
                break;

            default :
                values.put(DataBaseStatics.STATUS, DataBaseStatics.STATUS_FAILED);
                toastMessage=getBaseContext().getResources().getString(R.string.MessgeDeliverFailed_Title);
                break;
        }

        getBaseContext().getContentResolver().update(this_messageUri, values, null, null);


    }

}
```

and this is my send message method :

```
public void SendMessage(String sendingNumber , int index)
{
    String sNumber = sendingNumber;
    PendingIntent sentPI = sentPIs.get(index);


    PendingIntent deliverPI = deliverPIs.get(index);

    SmsManager sms =SmsManager.getDefault();
    ArrayList<String> msgparts = sms.divideMessage(message);
    if (msgparts.size()<=1)
    {
        sms.sendTextMessage(sNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliverPI);
    }
    else
    {
        sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(sNumber, null, msgparts, sentPIs, deliverPIs);
    }

}
```

Comment: The code you've posted is incomplete and a little unclear, but if it works when your friends phone is on, then it's an issue with their device/network.

Comment: @Mike M : tanks for your comment . but i use the word " phone turn off" to make my aim more clear . but if the phone is on and you use this code and send multi sms such that still the delivery of Previous delivery not received, this problem is occur.

Comment: @mike M : let me know Which part of code is not clear to explain it for you.